# Set is not working with overridden equals

Tags: java, object, set, equals, hashset

I was trying to use set.  so i tried this way

```
HashSet set=new HashSet();
Points p1 = new Points(10, 20);
Points p2 = new Points(10, 20);
System.out.println(set.add(p1)); // output true
System.out.println(set.add(p2));  // output false
```

I know my first output will be true and second will be false as Set will not allow duplicate elements. And, i also know Set achieve this by using equals(Object o) method. Which comes from java Object class with following signature.

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {}
```

For testing this little bit deeper i wrote my own class

```
class testSet{
    private int x;
    private int y;
    public testSet(int xa, int ya){
        this.x=xa;
        this.y=ya;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        if (o instanceof testSet){
            testSet ts=(testSet)o;
            return ts.x==this.x && ts.y==this.y;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now i am expecting following code will behave same as Point class

```
HashSet set=new HashSet();
testSet set_a=new testSet(3,4);
testSet set_b=new testSet(3,4);
System.out.println(set.add(set_a)); //output expected true
System.out.println(set.add(set_b)); //output expected false
```

So i am expecting first output will be true and second one false . But it is always returning true for both case. But did working for Point class. And i tried with following two Point implementations

```
android.graphics.Point
java.awt.point
```

So what i did wrong? Thanks for helping guys.

Comment: Here comes the duplicate answers...

Comment: Your `equals` should return false if `Object o` is not a `testSet`.

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake, in original implementation it was false. updated question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to override `hashCode` as well as `equals`.  The general contract of `hashCode` is that if two objects are equal (in the sense of `equals`), then they have the same hash code.

Comment: Yup, it's right in the docs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29 "Note that it is generally necessary to override the hashCode method whenever this method is overridden, so as to maintain the general contract for the hashCode method, which states that equal objects must have equal hash codes. "