# Set stored duplicate records

Tags: java, collections, set

Ok this might be easy question but I am confused when I read about set and the response I got.

I am fetching duplicate records form the database and using set to store only one record for one criteria(code) to ignore the remaining duplicate records.

```
Set<DiagnosisInfo> diagnosisInfoSet = patientDiagnosisHistoryRepository
                    .findBydiagnosisdesc(UUID.fromString(patientID.toUpperCase()));
```

And the response I got was

```
 "diagnosisInfo": [
    {
      "diagnosisCode": "T49.1X6S",
      "diagnosisCodeDescription": "Underdosing of antipruritics, sequela"
    },
    {
      "diagnosisCode": "T49.1X6S",
      "diagnosisCodeDescription": "Underdosing of antipruritics, sequela"
    },
    {
      "diagnosisCode": "T49.1X6S",
      "diagnosisCodeDescription": "Underdosing of antipruritics, sequela"
    },
    {
      "diagnosisCode": "T49.1X6S",
      "diagnosisCodeDescription": "Underdosing of antipruritics, sequela"
    },
    {
      "diagnosisCode": "V09.20",
      "diagnosisCodeDescription": "Pedestrian injured in traffic accident involving unspecified motor vehicles*"
    },
    {
      "diagnosisCode": "V09.20",
      "diagnosisCodeDescription": "Pedestrian injured in traffic accident involving unspecified motor vehicles*"
    },
    {
      "diagnosisCode": "V09.20",
      "diagnosisCodeDescription": "Pedestrian injured in traffic accident involving unspecified motor vehicles*"
    },
    {
      "diagnosisCode": "E09.8",
      "diagnosisCodeDescription": "Drug or chemical induced diabetes mellitus with unspecified complications"
    },
    {
      "diagnosisCode": "E09.8",
      "diagnosisCodeDescription": "Drug or chemical induced diabetes mellitus with unspecified complications"
    },
    {
      "diagnosisCode": "E09.8",
      "diagnosisCodeDescription": "Drug or chemical induced diabetes mellitus with unspecified complications"
    },
    {
      "diagnosisCode": "E09.8",
      "diagnosisCodeDescription": "Drug or chemical induced diabetes mellitus with unspecified complications"
    },
    {
      "diagnosisCode": "E09.8",
      "diagnosisCodeDescription": "Drug or chemical induced diabetes mellitus with unspecified complications"
    }
  ]
```

As we can see same diagnosis code records are displayed multiple times though they duplicates. The response I wanted to see is below

```
 "diagnosisInfo": [
    {
      "diagnosisCode": "T49.1X6S",
      "diagnosisCodeDescription": "Underdosing of antipruritics, sequela"
    },
    {
      "diagnosisCode": "V09.20",
      "diagnosisCodeDescription": "Pedestrian injured in traffic accident involving unspecified motor vehicles*"
    },
    {
      "diagnosisCode": "E09.8",
      "diagnosisCodeDescription": "Drug or chemical induced diabetes mellitus with unspecified complications"
    }
  ]
```

One response for one code. I do not know if I have to change my query, or something about set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is:

*As we can see same diagnosis code records are displayed multiple times though they duplicates.*

No, they are **not** the same. You have to implement a proper **equals()** and **hashCode()** method for your class DiagnosisInfo!

In order to determine that two objects are "the same"; the Set implementation will use the equals method provided by those objects. And most likely, you either forgot to @Override equals() in your class; your provided an implementation that results in `false`; even for those objects that you deem "to be the same".

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134254/set-is-not-working-with-overridden-equals) for some more details.

Given your latest comment, it still seems that you still have your logic **backwards**. You still think you "know" which objects are duplicates and which not. But what you think does **not** matter. The only thing that matters is the implementation within your equals() method. The result of that **operation** determines whether to objects are equal/similar; or if they are different.

So: when you add new fields to a class; and regenerate those methods using your IDE and now your "not happy" with the result; then your problem is that you **included** fields during the generation process that you actually think of as "should not matter". The code does what you **told** it to do.

Thus, the **real** answers here:

- You should step back and **rethink** your object model. You do not create/add fields and include (or not include) them when generating equals/hashCode methods because you *can* do that. Nope, you decide what **needs** to be done; and then you implement exactly that.
- And then: such code is **perfect** for unit testing and TDD. You don't wait for reading some real data; nope: you have various unit tests that **verify** that your equals implementation delivers the expected results. And then, when you add new stuff, or change code, you re-run those tests and they tell you about the things you broke.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I totally forgot the basics that we have to override equals and hashCode methods to compare two objects.

Comment: I have override the hashCode and Equals methods and it was working good yesterday without duplicates. Today I have added few more fields to the class and generated hashCode and Equals methods  and it is not working. Anything that I am missing? I am generating these methods from Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have up-voted two of your negative question. The problem is my requirement changed and I have to add couple of fields to class and re-generate hashCode and Equal methods. As per your updated answer I got it like it doesn't support if I update it later. Is that correct? If it doesn't support then how can I control these duplicate records? Do I have to write manual hashCode and equals methods instead of generating them by IDE?

Comment: The point is: you can at any time tell your IDE to re-generate these methods. But then, when you do that, **you** need to understand which of the fields should participate in those  methods. The IDE generates what you tell it to generate. You would only need to write them manually when the IDE isn't able to generate what you are looking for. If you have more specific questions, consider A) enhancing your question with more content; or B) putting up a new question  ... in both cases, drop me another comment ... but i wont have time before tomorrow.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will update my question. You can look into it when you have time :)

Comment: Sure will; just send me another comment; so that I get notified when you updated your question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is what you get when the DiagnosisInfo doesn override Equals and haschCode

your Set has no Idea  how to check when this object

```
{
  "diagnosisCode": "V09.20",
  "diagnosisCodeDescription": "Pedestrian injured in traffic accident involving unspecified motor vehicles*"
},
```

and this one

```
{
  "diagnosisCode": "V09.20",
  "diagnosisCodeDescription": "Pedestrian injured in traffic accident involving unspecified motor vehicles*"
},
```

are the same...

---

assuming the method you are invoking implements a `HashSet<E>` then, the spource code:

```
/**
 * Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present.
 * More formally, adds the specified element <tt>e</tt> to this set if
 * this set contains no element <tt>e2</tt> such that
 * <tt>(e==null&nbsp;?&nbsp;e2==null&nbsp;:&nbsp;e.equals(e2))</tt>.
 * If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set
 * unchanged and returns <tt>false</tt>.
 *
 * @param e element to be added to this set
 * @return <tt>true</tt> if this set did not already contain the specified
 * element
 */
public boolean add(E e) {
    return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
}
```

where map.put invokes **putVal**

and putval uses equals and hashcode... ha!

```
final V putVal(int hash, K key, V value, boolean onlyIfAbsent,
               boolean evict) {
    Node<K,V>[] tab; Node<K,V> p; int n, i;
    if ((tab = table) == null || (n = tab.length) == 0)
        n = (tab = resize()).length;
    if ((p = tab[i = (n - 1) & hash]) == null)
        tab[i] = newNode(hash, key, value, null);
    else {
        Node<K,V> e; K k;
        if (p.hash == hash &&
            ((k = p.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
            e = p;
        else if (p instanceof TreeNode)
            e = ((TreeNode<K,V>)p).putTreeVal(this, tab, hash, key, value);
        else {
            for (int binCount = 0; ; ++binCount) {
                if ((e = p.next) == null) {
                    p.next = newNode(hash, key, value, null);
                    if (binCount >= TREEIFY_THRESHOLD - 1) // -1 for 1st
                        treeifyBin(tab, hash);
                    break;
                }
                if (e.hash == hash &&
                    ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
                    break;
                p = e;
            }
        }
        if (e != null) { // existing mapping for key
            V oldValue = e.value;
            if (!onlyIfAbsent || oldValue == null)
                e.value = value;
            afterNodeAccess(e);
            return oldValue;
        }
    }
    ++modCount;
    if (++size > threshold)
        resize();
    afterNodeInsertion(evict);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help too. Your suggested code looks too difficult to understand for me. I am sorry I am kind of new.